# Lagrange multiplier calculation issue

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have 8 Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,  \lambda_3,\cdots, \lambda_8$.

And the Lagrange formulation is

$L(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,  \lambda_3,\cdots, \lambda_8) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{8} \lambda_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{8} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{8} \lambda_i \lambda_j  a_{i,j}$ with constraint

$\lambda_i \geq 0$ for all $1 \le i \le 8$ and

And auxiliary information is

$\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 -\lambda_3-\lambda_4+ \lambda_5+ \lambda_6 -\lambda_7+\lambda_8 = 0$

The matrix that supplies $a_{i,j}$ is shown below

\begin{pmatrix}
  0.36 &-0.472 & -0.542& -0.699 & 0.340 & 0.320 & -0.73 & 0.126 \\
 -0.472 & 0.612 & 0.700 & 0.905 & -0.441 & -0.414 & 0.94 & -0.163 \\
 -0.542 & 0.700 & 1.014 & 1.045 & -0.403 & -0.520 & 1.187 & -0.234 \\
 -0.699 & 0.905 & 1.045 & 1.3397 &-0.649 & -0.614 & 1.409 & -0.244  \\
 0.340 &  -0.441 & -0.403 & -0.649 & 0.368 & 0.276 & -0.637 & 0.095 \\
 0.320 & -0.414 & -0.520 & -0.614 & 0.276 & 0.290 & -0.664 & 0.121  \\
 -0.734 & 0.949 & 1.187 & 1.409 & -0.637 & -0.664 & 1.521 & -0.276 \\
 0.126 & -0.163 & -0.234 & -0.244 & 0.095 & 0.121 & -0.2763 & 0.054 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

I need to find $\lambda_i$ for $1 \le i \le 8$

**My approach** is as follows:

Calculate $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_i} $ for $1 \le i \le 8$,

Finally, I get *eight linear equations* in eight unknowns after calculating derivatives and one extra equation (given auxiliary information). Solving them gives all the desired values.

But, my approach is not working and I am getting wrong answers. the **correct answer** is $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2  \approx 65.52$ and $\lambda_k = 0$ for all other $k$'s.

Where am I going wrong?

**Note**: Please ignore auxiliary information in case of any issue.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here to help you.

Comment: @Ian Please tell me, what I need to add for completeness..

Comment: Well actually maybe we can. Did you set up KKT conditions? If the inequality constraint is "active" as it apparently should be then the ordinary Lagrange multiplier setup is not correct.

Comment: @Ian The second constraint given is auxiliary information. Except the non-negativity of Lagrange multipliers, there are no other active constraints.

Comment: The point is that the actual solution is supposed to be located on the surface where the inequality constraint becomes an equality constraint, so the solution presumably needs KKT conditions instead of simply looking for a critical point of the Lagrangian. I would guess that the critical point of the Lagrangian that you *did* find didn't satisfy $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: It might also help to mention the underlying optimization problem that these Lagrange multipliers came from in the first place if there is one.

Comment: @Ian It is around page no 55 of this link https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~dsamanta/courses/da/resources/slides/10SupportVectorMachine.pdf I formulated the above.

Comment: Page 49 contains all constraints,  I calculated all the related values and kept in a matrix inorder to make task easy.  @Ian

Comment: @Ian, yeah true, although solution exists, some of the multipliers are returning negative values. Making me sleepless for atleast two nights.

Comment: Yeah then your KKT conditions are set up incorrectly (possibly in the passage to the Lagrangian formulation in the first place).

Comment: @Ian but please check page no 16, the dual problem, I'm doing exactly the same.. https://web.mit.edu/6.034/wwwbob/svm.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZ9-a7jMnvAhUaeisKHRwMCTkQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw0ChiCvAhQQSouF9jEdUCr3

Answer (score 1):

Considering the lagrangian

$$
L(\lambda,\mu,s) = f(\lambda)+\mu_0(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 -\lambda_3-\lambda_4+ \lambda_5+ \lambda_6 -\lambda_7+\lambda_8)+\sum_{k=1}^8\mu_k(\lambda_k-s_k^2)
$$

with $f = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{8} \lambda_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{8} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{8} \lambda_i \lambda_j  a_{i,j}$

the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

Assuming $A=\{a_{i,j}\}$  as given, we obtain the stationary (feasible) points for $L$ as

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc}
f & \lambda_1&\lambda_2&\lambda_3&\lambda_4&\lambda_5&\lambda_6&\lambda_7&\lambda_8&s_1^2&s_2^2&s_3^2&s_4^2&s_5^2&s_6^2&s_7^2&s_8^2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.977804 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.977804 & 0.977804 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.977804 & 0.977804 \\
 1.10412 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.10412 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.10412 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.10412 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.10412 \\
 1.62602 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.62602 & 0 & 1.62602 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.62602 & 0 & 1.62602 & 0 \\
 1.66667 & 0 & 0 & 1.66667 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.66667 & 0 & 0 & 1.66667 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.66667 \\
 1.73611 & 0 & 0 & 1.73611 & 0 & 1.73611 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.73611 & 0 & 1.73611 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1.80868 & 0 & 0 & 1.12341 & 0 & 1.80868 & 0 & 0.685278 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.12341 & 0 & 1.80868 & 0 & 0.685278 & 0 \\
 1.889 & 0 & 0 & 1.889 & 0 & 1.04221 & 0 & 0 & 0.846795 & 0 & 0 & 1.889 & 0 & 1.04221 & 0 & 0 & 0.846795 \\
 2.07039 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.07039 & 2.07039 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.07039 & 2.07039 & 0 \\
 2.39808 & 2.39808 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.39808 & 0 & 2.39808 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.39808 & 0 \\
 2.44081 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.44081 & 2.44081 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.44081 & 2.44081 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2.48942 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.48942 & 0 & 2.48942 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.48942 & 0 & 2.48942 & 0 & 0 \\
 2.49559 & 0 & 0 & 0.460885 & 2.03471 & 2.49559 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.460885 & 2.03471 & 2.49559 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2.63818 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.63818 & 1.21954 & 1.41864 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.63818 & 1.21954 & 1.41864 & 0 & 0 \\
 2.94118 & 0 & 2.94118 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.94118 & 0 & 2.94118 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.94118 \\
 3.31455 & 3.31455 & 0 & 0 & 3.31455 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3.31455 & 0 & 0 & 3.31455 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 3.44828 & 3.44828 & 0 & 3.44828 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3.44828 & 0 & 3.44828 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 3.46975 & 3.46975 & 0 & 3.10338 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.366371 & 0 & 3.46975 & 0 & 3.10338 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.366371 & 0 \\
 3.78788 & 0 & 0 & 3.78788 & 0 & 0 & 3.78788 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3.78788 & 0 & 0 & 3.78788 & 0 & 0 \\
 4.01689 & 0 & 0 & 3.05722 & 0.959667 & 0 & 4.01689 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3.05722 & 0.959667 & 0 & 4.01689 & 0 & 0 \\
 4.3517 & 4.3517 & 0 & 2.27239 & 2.07931 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4.3517 & 0 & 2.27239 & 2.07931 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 10.2041 & 0 & 10.2041 & 0 & 0 & 10.2041 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10.2041 & 0 & 0 & 10.2041 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 13.5135 & 0 & 13.5135 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13.5135 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13.5135 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13.5135 & 0 & 0 \\
 13.7805 & 0 & 12.6829 & 1.09756 & 0 & 0 & 13.7805 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12.6829 & 1.09756 & 0 & 0 & 13.7805 & 0 & 0 \\
 17.1994 & 0 & 17.1994 & 0 & 0 & 6.6526 & 10.5468 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 17.1994 & 0 & 0 & 6.6526 & 10.5468 & 0 & 0 \\
 35.7143 & 35.7143 & 35.7143 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 35.7143 & 35.7143 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

here $s_k = 0$ indicates that the respective restriction is actuating.